# Find the indexes of unique elements of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list like this:

```
l=[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]
```

We can see that the list list contains 5 unique values with 8 total values.

I want the indexes of the unique values from the list in list format.

So the output looks like:

```
indexes=[0,1,3,4,5]
```

How to do it most efficient way using python ?

Comment: if this is a pandas series, just do `pd.Series(l).drop_duplicates().index` else if this is a list, you dont need pandas ,

Comment: `l.index[~l.duplicated()]` is `l` is a Series

Comment: Is this specifically a  pandas question? It's tagged `pandas` but there's nothing pandas-specific in the question.

Comment: Where is your approach of solving this? What is your specific problem with your code? Where is your [mre]? What did you try?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried to solve your problem as well. In its present state, your question shows no effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use built-in types for this.

**CODE**

```py
l=[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]

indexes = [l.index(x) for x in set(l)]
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

- [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) 
  All unique members of the list.
- [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) 
  Returns the first index of an element.

---

**COMMENT**

As pointed out in the comments, if order is important for you, you can either use `sorted` on the `set` or on the resulting index list depending on the data that is provided. If the data is already sorted, I would suggest to do it like this:

```
indexes = [l.index(x) for x in sorted(set(l))]
```

Comment: index() will return the position of the first occurance

Comment: Right, @mamun but will `set(l)` iterate the items in order?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. He needs to perform `sort()` later to get the order of index correct, or there needs to be better way.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It was not specified by OP, but we can use `sorted` to have the indexes in order... @mamun "s.index(x) = index of the first occurrence of x in s" - from [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Answer (score 18):

why did no one mention `np.unique` in here??

```
import numpy as np
np.unique([1,6,6,2,2,3,4,5,5,5], return_index=True)

>>> (array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1], dtype=int64))
```

the first array contains the (**sorted**) unique values and the second array (returned if `return_index` is set to `True`) is a list of the indexes of the first occurrences

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate through your list. The first time you see an item add it to a set indicating it's been seen and add the number to the result list. Skip the others. This will keep the indexes in the order the item are first seen in the list:

```
def uniqueIndexes(l):
    seen = set()
    res = []
    for i, n in enumerate(l):
        if n not in seen:
            res.append(i)
            seen.add(n)
    return res

l=[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,2]

uniqueIndexes(l)
```

**results:**

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a pandas-specific question, and `l` is just a plain old list, I'd go over it and keep an ordered map from the value to the first index holding it. Then, you can return the map values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def get_unique_indexes(l):
    # OrdedDict is used to preserve the order of the indexes
    result = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
        val = l[i]
        if not val in result:
            result[val] = i

    return result.values()
```

Comment: I would use `for i, val in enumerate(l):` rather range with len.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done:

```
l=[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5] # Your list
indexes=[] # Your output list
for elem in set(l):
       indexes.append(l.index(elem))
```

In the for loop, each element of the set is taken and the index of the element in the list is taken out using list.index() method (which returns the index of the first element of the required type) and the value is inserted into the indexes list.

This is how it works.(I like to explain, so please apologize for my lengthy writing!)

Thank You.